# discord.py - how do i keep the bot up and running while waiting for a input()

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I think my problem is i can't keep the bot awake while waiting for input i've tried a few things but nothing seems to help

````
import os
import re
import discord
MyDiscordID = os.environ["DiscordID"] # my discord account id
people = os.environ["people"] # input everyone i want to dm
message = os.environ["message"] # input message
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all(), token=os.environ["Token"]) # discord intents & bot token
names = [people, "yourself"] # yourself for testing
names = str(names).replace("'", "")
@client.event
async def on_ready():
  while True:
     user = input("send the dms to who? ")
                                           # stay alive while waiting
     if user == "yourself":
       user = await client.fetch_user(MyDiscordID)
       await user.send("# ```(This message was generated by a bot)```")
       await user.send(message)
       print("you sent the dm to yourself")
     if user not in names:
       print("no user found with that id")
... 

@client.event
````

i'm trying to make a bot that dms certain people certain phrases in the future i want to make it automated from when i get a dm (which i already have setup) but i can't seem to get it to wait for the input
i'm using replit to host the code

after left for 10 seconds i get the following error message:

```
send the dms to who? 2023-10-18 19:10:01 WARNING  discord.gateway Shard ID None heartbeat blocked for more than 10 seconds.
Loop thread traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/guild-members/main.py", line 38, in <module>
    client.run(os.environ["Token"])
  File "/home/runner/guild-members/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 860, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "/nix/store/xf54733x4chbawkh1qvy9i1i4mlscy1c-python3-3.10.11/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/nix/store/xf54733x4chbawkh1qvy9i1i4mlscy1c-python3-3.10.11/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 636, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "/nix/store/xf54733x4chbawkh1qvy9i1i4mlscy1c-python3-3.10.11/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 603, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/nix/store/xf54733x4chbawkh1qvy9i1i4mlscy1c-python3-3.10.11/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1909, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "/nix/store/xf54733x4chbawkh1qvy9i1i4mlscy1c-python3-3.10.11/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "/home/runner/guild-members/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 441, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/guild-members/main.py", line 12, in on_ready
    user = input("send the dms to who? ")
```

(edited once)

Comment: Hey, I think you are new to coding, so I want to give a few tips. Instead of using `while 1 == 1` you can just say `while True`. The next problem is the issue you describe makes it sound like you aren't starting the bot. You might want to post a fully reproducible version, as no one reading can assume what exactly is happening. This is mostly a Discord API issue, but still worth mentioning; Discord limits DM messages by bots quite a bit, so you might have issues sending them automated. For example, if you want to send too many messages at once, you would get rate limited by the API.

Comment: Hey, yes this is my first coding project, thank you for the information about  `while True`. I have updated my previous question with more information about what is happening hopefully someone can help now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start a separate thread and take the input through that thread.
I am sure there is a better way to do this (Maybe with cogs, but I'm not familiar with them) however still a technically works solution.
The example is to just to show what you can do for a quick and dirty solution.

```
from threading import Thread


from discord import Client, Intents, Message

client = Client(intents=Intents.default())
messages = []


@client.event
async def on_message(message: Message):
    if client.user.id == message.author.id:
        return
    if messages:
        new_message = messages.pop()
        await message.channel.send(content=new_message)
    else:
        await message.channel.send(content="No new messages.")


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    Thread(target=lambda: messages.append(input()), daemon=True).start()


client.run("YOUR_TOKEN")
```